# Using array.from() with element in local storage (Angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, local-storage

I'm trying to create an array with number of elements dependent on the value stored in local storage but I don't exactly know how to refer to it properly using the `array.from()` method. I need to generate a number of input fields with 2 checkboxes and then store everything in an array. But I get stuck:

COMPONENT.TS:

```
constructor() {
    this.showStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightdetails")) || {};
   }

public passengers = Array.from({ length: parseInt(localStorage['flightdetails.passengersNumber']) }, _ => 
({ name: '', child: false, luggage: false })); //**here is what I have but it does not work**
The number of passengers is stored as passengersNumber in localStorage
```

HTML Component:

```
<li *ngFor="let passenger of passengers; let i=index">
  <input type="text" [name]="'name_' + 1" [(ngModel)]="passenger.name" placeholder="Name and surname">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="passenger.child" (change)="passenger.child = !passenger.child">Child
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="passenger.luggage" (change)="passenger.luggage = ! passenger.luggage">Luggage
</li>
```

Thanks for any support in solving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage['flightdetails.passengersNumber']` is looking for an entry in localStorage with the key 'flightdetails.passengersNumber'. You need to parse it first to access properties on the stored object
as it is a string `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightdetails")).passengersNumber`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you need, but you can try change this line

```
    public passengers = Array.from({ length: parseInt(localStorage['flightdetails.passengersNumber']) }, _ => ({ name: '', child: false, luggage: false }));
```

to:

```
public passengers = Array.from({ length: (JSON.parse(localStorage['flightdetails']||'{}')).passengersNumber || 2 }, _ => ({ name: '', child: false, luggage: false }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a value for `flightdetails.passengersNumber` in `localStorage`? `localStorage` is a key-value store. So if there is a value stored for the key `abc`, a completely unrelated object can be stored under `abc.def`. If you want to access `flightdetails.passengersNumber`, something has to be stored for this very key.

If you want to make it dependent of the object in `localStorage['flightdetails']`, you can use `Array.from({ length: this.showStorage.passengersNumber}, ...)`

Also, as a sidenote, better always use `parseInt(x, 10)` than `parseInt(x)` with the radix argument (otherwise numbers with leading `0` will convert the number from octal).